# Covert POST CURL TO NODE TRANSITION

Tags: api, curl

I'm pretty new at coding and I've learned some JS, Node Express, and SQL.
I would like to integrate into an API.
The documentation I've got is showing cURL examples which I don't know how to translate into something I'm familiar with...

I need to make a post call as follows:

```
curl —X POST -­c cookies.txt —d "login=demo&password=demo42"
https://www.thisistheapi.com/console/login_proxy.php
```

that on successful login will give me a JSON encoded output with an authentication token that will be used to call the API service.
This token is also stored in a cookie and the cookie must be passed on the
following API requests.
E.g.

```
{"token":"6333531373034343433623663642342656939373831673423e44323334663"}
```

How do I set that up to run on node environment?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out some Express.JS tutorials, it'll help you learning Node and provides an easy framework to work with:
http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

It'll be something like this:

```
app.post('/api/users', function(req, res) {
    var user_id = req.body.id;
    var password = req.body.password;       

    res.json(yourJSONvariableHere);
});
```